# Add an APN to Samsung Galaxy S3 running 4.1.1

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-3, apn

I am traveling internationally and have replaced my Verizon SIM card with a local one.  To get data, I need to add an APN.  I can't do this using settings -- no option to add exists.  Is there another way to do this?  And app maybe?  I do *not* want to root my phone.

Comment: You might ask your "local provider" if they can send you a "service SMS". I know that worked in former times with Symbian devices, and I heard a similar thing should work on Android devices as well. Just make it clear to them you're having an Android device, they should be familar with that.

Comment: @Izzy Doesn't really work on Android :(

Comment: I never tried, so to me that's just hear-say -- which is why I put it in a comment as a "maybe" instead of making it an answer. Maybe somebody who already had experience with it can confirm/deny it?

Comment: If you know the number and provider of the local SIM card, chances are there's their website in which it will explain by texting to a certain number that, it will send out the configuration by sms, or manually enter it in.

Comment: I'm back home now.  I never was able to solve this problem.  I actually went out a purchased a new SIM card + 1 month of service ($21 total) from a different local provider, but this didn't help either.  Cell phone service did improve, so I kept it.  It also was about 90% cheaper than the original service that I arranged.

Answer (score 4):

I have been told by Verizon that it's a bug on the Samsung Note 2 and S3 after Jelly bean. Verizon / Samsung are working on a fix so you can modify the APN in near future.

Verizon didn't intend a deliberate prevention on their part (confirmed by the fact Verizon HTC Droid Incredible 2 running android DOES allow you to modify the APN and works perfectly for calls/text/data overseas). I have both so I should know

Roll on a fix fast....

Answer (score 2):

I am from the USA and have the Verizon S3 with Jelly Bean. I am currently in the UK. Used my usual UK VodaFone Sim card and it immediately worked for both Voice and Texts (something it didn't do when I was here in November before the Jelly Bean Update).

The reason it won't work at all in SOME countries is actually SIMPLY (but major) because Verizon seem to have disabled the ability to modify or add an APN. It just so happens, in the UK, their default APN works (for text and voice) on the VodaFone UK network. I've been here a week and text / phone all over the world. Since I can't edit the APN though, I cannot set the settings needed for Data.

My wife has a Verizon Incredible 2 and her phone works in the UK for Voice, Text AND data but only after I modiified the APN (which the Incredible allows).

Luckily, I brought my HTC unlocked phone as well. I use that with a VodaFone UK Sim card in that as well (SIMS are free) plus a 5 pound top-up for 500MB data. I simply turn that into a mobile hotspot when I'm outside and have my Verizon S3 use WIFI to that. Net effect is the same cost wise but it's a shame Verizon missed this feature. No doubt it's a bug and the people I deal with in Verizon (business side) at investigating.

Still. - now you know. It WILL work as a true GLOBAL phone (Verizon rates). For 3rd party SIM cards - It WILL now at last work as a phone/text in some countries. It WILL NOT work if you need to mod the APN to get any of the features for any country you are in - until Verizon fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I am having this problem too after inserting local SIM. Calls and texts are OK, I need to configure an APN for internet.

A Verizon Global Support Technician told me that it is beyond Verizon's control to add an APN and that Samsung will need to provide directions on how to do this.  I got online to chat with Samsung and the guy told me he can't help me on chat, I need to call this number:

1-888-987-4357, Mon-Fri: 7 AM - 9 PM (CST), Sat: 9 AM - 6 PM (CST)

Comment: So, did it work?

Comment: No, Samsung said that they install the hardware and software and once they send it out, the carrier (Verizon) has full control over the data settings, adding/removing APN's etc.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the save option for APN is not active on android 4.1.1 (at least when you have zero APN previously stored.

But after creating a new APN and filling parameters, if you shut down completely the device, (and do not try to activate save option through the button, act that would erase all parameters introduced), it will be saved somewhere.
You will be able to access to your newly stored APN after restart (and pin unlock your sim card). 
This works with upstream settings set with modempoweron, data-enabled and itinerance enabled

Answer (score 0):

The option to add a new APN is in `System Settings->More->Mobile Networks->Access Point Names` then press the menu button and select add.

If that setting isn't there (and it should be), then you will not be able to add an APN without root, as the 'bug' that allowed apps to add and edit APN's was fixed in Android 4.

Comment: This is exactly my issue.  When I press the menu button the only option is "Reset to Default" (on my S3).  My wife's RAZR works as you have described.

Comment: @Gdalya It must have been disabled by your network... You will have to be rooted.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an attempt by Verizon to cripple the data capabilities of the phone and force you to use their network.

While in Germany with a [LIDL](http://lidl.de)'s SIM Card, the data, text and voice all work when on a wireless network connection.  Once the SIM Card is connected to the LIDL network alone, voice and messaging work, but not data.

There is no way to access the APN page in the US or abroad and calls to Verizon support indicate there are no plans to do so and there is no workaround.

Will try rooting the phone.

Answer (score 0):

How to add apn to verizon samasung galaxy s3 (Root required)

<sup>(I found this from some forum while I was searching for how to add APN for my brothers Verizon S3. It worked 100%. All credits go to the guy who posted it there. I didn't remember the address. And sorry for my bad english. by the way I am from MaLdives.)</sup>

1. Go to market install BuildProp Editor
2. Once installed find and open Build Prop Editor
3. Hit the menu button and select Edit
4. Scroll to the bottom of screen and add the following lines

   ```
   ril.sales_code=LOL
   ro.csc.sales_code=LOL
   ```
5. Hit the save button at the top right hand corner of the screen(looks like a disk)
6. Once this is done saving restart the phone
7. After restarting go to *Settings>More Settings>Mobile Networks>Access Point Names>Menu Button>+ New APN*
8. Add desired carriers APN info, when finished hit menu button and save
9. Power down and change to your desired SIM card if you hadn't already done so
10. Power back on and go to Settings>More Settings>Mobile Networks> Access Point Names (if done properly you should see the APN data you entered for your respective carrier).
11. Select the respective APN listing and then you should have working data

Congrats you can now natively add in any APN desired.

Answer (score -1):

Use tweakker app for APN editing. It has different carriers and networks in it. It will tell you how to setup your APN.

Comment: Pardon? Can you give a few more details what you are talking about? A link to the app would be helpful :)